# Do fractal objects exist in the real world?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, fractals

I'm talking about a fractal in terms of [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) or [Minkowski–Bouligand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) dimension.

Thinking about the Chaos Theory for a while, I have a question about real-world fractals.
I've found appropriate articles about asphalt [Fractal dimension analysis of the fine aggregate gradation of interlocking skeleton asphalt mixture](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11595-011-0269-2) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225724814_Fractal_dimension_analysis_of_the_fine_aggregate_gradation_of_interlocking_skeleton_asphalt_mixture)) and skin [A fractal-like structure in the skin](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218348X96000194).
Also, there is a well-known example with a [coastline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension) and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension#Random_and_natural_fractals).

My intuition says that given a quantizable world without quantum effects, there are no fractals. A subquestion: is this intuition right?

Quantum effects make me feel confused.
I've got only one semester of Quantum Physics in university because my major was Mathematics, so I know really little about the quantum world.
The following things make me think that it may be impossible to calculate the Minkowski or Hausdorff dimension of quantum objects (and macro objects, consisting of the quantum ones):

- First, observation of tiny objects like electrons is tricky, so we don't even really know their shape.
- Second, the wave-particle duality.
- Third, the Heisenberg inequality, which may not allow us to calculate coverage of quantum objects.

I can formulate my question in four parts:

- Are there proven fractal real-world objects?
- Are there proven non-fractal real-world objects?
- Are these questions still unsolved?
- Are these questions correct? Is there something (like Heisenberg inequality) that makes these questions incorrect/unsolvable?

Comment: Isn't the canonical example of a coastline (supply by Mandelbrot) a valid example?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, let's imagine that we have "frozen" the coastline (make it -100C cold), and measure it. Given a big scale (radius of covering circles is smaller than a grain of sand), we will have something like a broken line, which is a 1D object I guess (am I wrong?). Though, I can't speak for a huge scale, when the radius equals the classical electron radius.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples of *approximately* fractal objects like coastlines.

But the definition of fractal is that something is self-similar at *all* scales. That’s not physical. As you go down in scale, there are clear changes in structure below the scale of atoms and below the scale of nuclei.

So yes, there are many examples of fractal-like structure, but truly scale-invariant fractal objects don’t exist in this Universe.

Comment: Is self-similarity a definition of being a fractal? I was taught that a fractal is an object with a fractional Minkowski dimension.

Comment: That’s equivalent, in the sense that both require similarity at all scales. Would you consider something ‘fractal’ if it’s Minkowski dimension doesn’t event exist at some scales?

Comment: I don't know what to do if the Minkowski/Hausdorff dimension doesn't exist. This was a part of my question. Also, I'm not sure whether it exists or doesn't exist, and need a reference.

Answer (score 0):

No mathematical objects exist in the real world. However in Mandelbrot's book there are plenty of famous examples of objects with fractal scaling such as the coastline of Britain.

Comment: Yes, I know about the coastline, and I've also mentioned objects like asphalt and skin. If you say "No", please, give a reference to scientific papers where someone proves that there are no objects with fractal dimensions in the real world, and there are only objects with integral dimension. Though, the objects with integral dimension are mathematical too, so they shouldn't exist by this logic either.

Answer (score 0):

True fractals that maintain scale invariance to any degree do not exist in the real world because, for example, if the fractal pattern is caused by forces between atoms and molecules, once your scale length is shorter than a molecule the "fractality" comes to a halt.

I experienced an almost-textbook example of a fractal when observing the microscopic wetting dynamics of a surfactant-doped ink on a rhodium-plated surface. In this case, the fractal wetting patterns disappeared on short length scales because the contact angle of the ink on the rhodium eventually caused the arms and tendrils of the fractal pattern to intersect. On larger scales they were stunning.

Comment: Okay, let's imagine my scale length is shorter than a molecule. Quantum effects occur and it's hard to measure anything. So, does Hausdorff or Minkowski dimension exist there at all? If you say that the "fractality" comes to a halt, then it means that the Hausdorff dimension becomes equal to the topological one either doesn't make sense because of quantum effects (I'm not sure exactly which ones and why).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that physics gives the ultimate model of geometry of the Universe. Alas, it doesn't. Currently there's no physical model correct down to infinitely fine details. Moreover, we can't even prove that some of future models will have such correctness, since to check to infinite precision would require making infinitely many measurements.

Fractals are defined by the property which must be maintained to infinitely fine scale, so they can't be found in nature with complete confidence. They are actually only mathematical models. In real world we can only apply them as approximations to real objects. But fractals aren't unique in this: smooth objects also don't exist in real world. Can you e.g. find a mathematical cube in real world? What about a sphere? Any other smooth shape? At best, probability density could be smooth (cf. atomic orbitals, although they do have some cusps), but not what we would consider an *object*: it's a theoretical construct, and not a measurable quantity.

Comment: I don't assume this but may have mentioned this problem under "quantum effects". Sure we have no smooth objects as well as any ideal shapes in the real world. We cannot use the infinite scale as well. Does this mean that we cannot say anything about being a fractal or a non-fractal about a real-world object (and calculate its dimension)?

Comment: @Charlie if we can't measure nor predict anything about an object beyond some scale, then we can't tell whether the fractal self-similarity will continue. Since Hausdorff dimension is defined via an infimum, we can't prove that it has a particular value if we don't have access to infinitely fine details. Similarly for Minkowski dimension, which is defined via a limit. We can only say that a particular object is geometrically like a fractal with some particular Hausdorff dimension _in a given range of scales_.

Comment: As well as we cannot say anything about the topological dimension of the space, because it needs $\varepsilon$-coverage for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon > 0$, and we cannot even guarantee that space still metric under huge scale, so objects cannon be assumed to have any Lebesque dimension at all, right?

Comment: @Charlie right, and there are multiple [physical theories with extra dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_dimensions), which haven't been ruled out.

Comment: okay, if we cannot scale up to arbitrary fine details, are there alternative fractal definitions using discrete spaces? I've found an article "Dimension of discrete fractal spaces" of 1988 but I'm not sure whether it or something of the kind is used to determine fractal dimension in the "microworld"